# jQuery UI - append the selected item to the input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using `jQuery UI` with autocomplete to suggest usernames for a message recipient. But since the message can be sent to many recipients I don't want autocomplete to clear the input after selecting an element. I tried this via the `select:` action but it doesn't work like I want it to work. The recipient field should look as the below mentioned string after adding multiple recipients:

```
Username1, Username2, Username3
```

This is my code:

```
$( "#message_recipient" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        if($('#message_recipient').val().indexOf(",") != -1){
            var pieces = $.trim($('#message_recipient').val()).split(/[\s,]+/);
            var last_piece = $.trim(pieces[pieces.length-1]);
        } else {
            var last_piece = $.trim($('#message_recipient').val());
        }

        if(last_piece!=""){
            $.ajax({
                url: baseurl+"users/search_for_user",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    user_name: last_piece
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.result, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.user_name,
                            value: item.user_name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#message_recipient').val($('#message_recipient').val()+ui.item.label+", ");
    },
    open: function() {

    },
    close: function() {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Tag-It!](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html?) library. There you can see how the underlying input field actually contains the required commas. You don't need to have additional logic for that case.
Check out '***Single Input Field***' on that page.

Just add the library and start using it.